# Remove pixels below threshold with Photon

Tags: javascript, webassembly

Using the [Photon_rs](https://github.com/silvia-odwyer/photon) library, I'm looking to take an image, and remove any pixels (set to black) any whos R, G, and B values are below their respective specified thresholds.

Ex: R32, G75, B44
I want to set to black any pixel who has all 3 channels below their threshold.

I tried doing something like

```js
photon.remove_red_channel(image, tRed)
photon.remove_green_channel(image, tGreen)
photon.remove_blue_channel(image, tBlue)
```

But that removes the channel from pixels whos other values are above the threshold. So like increasing the red value would cause the image to entirely shift away from red. (Aka it would take all pxiels with `red_channel < tRed` and remove the red, even if the other 2 values were above their thresholds).

I want it to only affect pixels whos channel values are within the thresholds.